# FlowLayoutPanel VerticalScroll how to use?

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-scrolling, flowlayoutpanel

My question refers to the previous one:
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924318/how-to-make-list-in-c-sharp-windows-forms-with-usercontrol)
I want to add the scrolling option to the `FlowLayautPanel` control, but I don't know how to associate adding a new row with `UserControl`, with `VerticalScroll` so that after moving it there will be visible rows that are not visible.

Below I have tried on my own to add the option of scrolling, but the content of `FlowLayaoutControl` shifts slower than owl, and when it reaches the end, you can not see the last lines.

```
  public partial class ImportManager : Form
    {
        public ImportManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 100;
        }


        private void DodajWierszButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new importRow());
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.LargeChange -= 1;
        }
    }
```

I would add that I am a beginner in window programming and the solution is probably trivial, but I am not able to solve it at the moment.
I would like the `FlowLayoutPanel` to be able to send lines.

Comment: LargeChange Value decrements that's why. I think.

Comment: Just set the panel's AutoScroll property to *true* in the designer.